# Why can my local docker image see one external host and not the other?

Tags: docker, network-programming

- I am running a docker container on my PC as follows: docker run -it my_container /bin/bash.
- Outside of docker, my PC has network access to remote hosts machine1.sydney.network and machine2.sydney.network.
- When I run a container of my image, I can access (ping) machine1.sydney.network, but NOT machine2.sydney.network from within the container.
- Both machine1.sydney.network and machine2.sydney.network are on the same subnet
- Our network engineers have confirmed firewall settings are good for both machine1.sydney.network and machine2.sydney.network
- in response to a suggestion that I might need include a script to modify ip routing, the network team say "you should just be able to use the standard routing the gateway here will direct traffic as required"

I am new to Docker so perhaps am missing an obvious config.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here?

ie: is there something I can add to my "docker run" script to make both remote machines visible from within my docker container?

Cheers,

Chris

---

NSLOOKUP and DIG information from inside the container included below.
**Note:** I am now in a different office (on a different subnet) in our organisation  to when I first posted the original query.  In this office, my docker container cannot acccess either of machine1 or machine2.  However I can still access them when outside of my docker container.

```
MACHINE 1
=========

root@cb4b66d8ad7e:/# nslookup machine1.sydney.network
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   machine1.sydney.network
Address: 172.16.32.20

----------------------------------

root@cb4b66d8ad7e:/# dig machine1.sydney.network
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> machine1.sydney.network
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12578
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;machine1.sydney.network.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
machine1.sydney.network. 1916 IN      A       172.16.32.20

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 30 23:53:05 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70



MACHINE 2
=========

root@cb4b66d8ad7e:/# nslookup machine2.sydney.network
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   machine2.sydney.network
Address: 172.17.32.115

----------------------------------

root@cb4b66d8ad7e:/# dig machine2.sydney.network
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> machine2.sydney.network
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42566
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;machine2.sydney.network.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
machine2.sydney.network. 60   IN      A       172.17.32.115

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 30 23:48:45 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
```

Comment: Can you try `nslookup` or `dig` and paste the outputs here . If ICMP is not enabled on `machine2` you may not get responses for your `ping`.

Comment: Is that nslookup from within the container? 
So for example:
$ nslookup machine1.sydney.network
and
$ nslookup machine1.sydney.network

Also, ping aside, I on machine1 I can connect to one of its postgres DBs.  I cannot connect to any postgres DBs on machine2.

(Just an example of one extra thing I tried besides PING)

PS: I am off-network now but will do nslookup and dig as soon as back on network and postback here. :)